# Making a binary tree using an array in C

Tags: c, tree

If I want to make a binary tree from an array in the following order:

Example: for the following array: `{ -1, 17, -1, 3, -1, -1, -1, 55, -1, 4, -1, 15, 11, 2, 3 }` the following tree is created:

```
           55

     15         3

  2     4     *    17

3 11  *   *      *    *
```

The function is recursive and returns a Tree input: the array and it's size. The tree nodes can only receive positive values from the array so `-1` wont be considered. `*` means `NULL` prototype: `Tree BuildTreeFromArray(int *arr, int size)`.

Would very much appreciate the help.

This is what I had so far and it's working but I don't really like it.

```
Tree BuildTreeFromArray(int  *arr, int  size)
{
    Tree resTree;
    Tree right;
    Tree left;
    resTree.root = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    checkMemoryAllocation(resTree.root);
    int halfSize;

    if (size == 1)
    {
        resTree.root->data = arr[0];
        resTree.root->left = NULL;
        resTree.root->right = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        halfSize = size / 2;
    resTree.root->data = arr[halfSize];

    if (arr[halfSize/2] != -1)
    {//we check if there's a valid array data we can input to the tree
        left = BuildTreeFromArray(arr, halfSize);
        resTree.root->left = left.root;
    }
    else
        resTree.root->left = NULL;

    if (arr[halfSize + (halfSize / 2) + 1] != -1)
    {
        right = BuildTreeFromArray(arr + halfSize + 1, halfSize);
        resTree.root->right = right.root;
    }
    else
        resTree.root->right = NULL;

    }
    return resTree;
}
```

Could this be written in a different version?

Answer (score 1):

- Do not cast the `malloc` value. It serves no purpose, and may mask a serious problem.
- Allocating `sizeof(TreeNode)` assumes the knowledge of the type of `resTree.root`, and results in the double maintenance. A preferred idiom is `malloc(sizeof(*resTree.root))`.
- As written, the node tests for validity of its (future) children. It is more natural for the node to test its own validity:

  ```
  if (size == 0) {
      return NULL;
  }

  halfSize = size/2;
  if (arr[halfSize == -1) {
      return NULL;
  }

  resTree.root = malloc(sizeof(*resTree.root));
  resTree.root->data = data;
  resTree.root->left = BuildTreeFromArray(....).root;
  resTree.root->right = BuildTreeFromArray(....).root;

  return resTree;
  ```
- I don see a reason why `TreeNode` is wrapped into `Tree`. More context would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid using recursive function calls in c (or similar languages)

The available calls stack memory will always be a limited resource, and won't fit for an arbitrary depth of function calls (and thus your tree size would be also limited).

You can always avoid using recursion by providing a dynamic stack data structure and an appropriate loop.

## Fix your indentation and always use a clear scope

Your indentation is broken and the scope of statements is unclear at several places (my comments starting with `!!!`):

> ```
> Tree BuildTreeFromArray(int  *arr, int  size)
> {
>     // ...
>     if (size == 1)
>     {
>         // ...
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         halfSize = size / 2;
>     resTree.root->data = arr[halfSize]; // !!! Should be indented according the enclosing scope block
>     // ...
>     if (arr[halfSize/2] != -1)
>     {//we check if there's a valid array data we can input to the tree
>        // ...
>     }
>     else // !!! Missing scope block
>         resTree.root->left = NULL; 
>
>     if (arr[halfSize + (halfSize / 2) + 1] != -1)
>     {
>        // ...
>     }
>     else // !!! Missing scope block
>         resTree.root->right = NULL;
>
>     }
>     return resTree;
> }
> ```

Here's the fully fixed version (I'm not sure that will provide exactly the same logic as you currently have it):

```
Tree BuildTreeFromArray(int  *arr, int  size)
{
    Tree resTree;
    Tree right;
    Tree left;
    resTree.root = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    checkMemoryAllocation(resTree.root);
    int halfSize;

    if (size == 1)
    {
        resTree.root->data = arr[0];
        resTree.root->left = NULL;
        resTree.root->right = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        halfSize = size / 2;
        resTree.root->data = arr[halfSize];

        if (arr[halfSize/2] != -1)
        {//we check if there's a valid array data we can input to the tree
            left = BuildTreeFromArray(arr, halfSize);
            resTree.root->left = left.root;
        }
        else
        {
            resTree.root->left = NULL;
        }
        if (arr[halfSize + (halfSize / 2) + 1] != -1)
        {
            right = BuildTreeFromArray(arr + halfSize + 1, halfSize);
            resTree.root->right = right.root;
        }
        else
        {
            resTree.root->right = NULL;
        }
    }
    return resTree;
}
```

Comment: Using a `dynamic stack data structure` is the same as using recursion. The difference you are manually implementing the structure. If you are going to run out of stack space you are probably going to run out of `dynamic stack data structure` as they both use memory.

Comment: @Loki I seriously disagree, since the available stack storage is limited to a _way smaller_ amount of memory than dynamic memory allocation would allow.

Comment: That is a misunderstanding of how stacks work. Stacks will grow to fill memory. Memory Full => (Dynamically allocated space + Stack space) exceeds addressable space. All modern OS will dynamically increase the amount of space used by there stack as required.

Comment: @LokiAstari _" All modern OS will dynamically increase the amount of space used by there stack as required."_ What do you consider falling under that category? FreeRTOS (nope), Embedded Linux (nope), bare metal (nope).

Comment: Not heard of FreeRTOS. But the other two, yes. Though they don't dynamically allocate; the stack and heap just grow towards each other until they crash together. There is no fixed size. So if we limit our discussion to the point on hand. Dynamically allocate space and growing the stack are basically the same thing. Eventually you run out of space as the total space is the space used by the combination of both.

Comment: @Loki _"Not heard of FreeRTOS."_ With that programming expertise, under what rock are you living? Windows programming solely? (no offense)

Comment: You can't say that FreeRTOS and friends have less stack space than heap. They do not map memory dynamically, and it is up to the linker script (that is up to the programmer) how much memory goes to stack, and how much to heap. The only architecture I know with really limited stack is 8051, but... you know. That said, recursion is very useful tool, and its educational value is immense. The recommendation to OP to avoid it is at least badly timed.

Comment: I must admit I have never seen "stack growing" in embedded programming. You can get a stack overflow in a Windows C# application with a recursive loop [quite easily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28656872/69809), and I would expect the default ratio for a 256kB microcontroller to be something like 8kB stack vs 240kB heap. Having a huge stack is a waste of resources that could potentially be shared among different parts of the program - anything with a lifetime longer than a single function body must be heap-allocated (unless statically allocated, of course).